# Using cvSplit(): I'm getting a BW pic instead of a colored pic

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm using cvSplit() to separate RGB channels and print them in 3 different images showing colors r, g, and b. But I only got BW images with black and white pics. Is this the correct output when using cvSplit()? or I have to do something to make it colored? 
Below is my code so far.

```
![#include <iostream>
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>
#include "rgb.h"

using namespace std;

int main(){
IplImage* img = cvLoadImage("rgb.jpg");



IplImage* channelRed = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(img), 8, 1);
IplImage* channelGreen = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(img), 8, 1);
IplImage* channelBlue = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(img), 8, 1);



IplImage* Result1 = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(img), 8, 1);
IplImage* Result2 = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(img), 8, 1);
IplImage* Result3= cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(img), 8, 1);



cvSplit(img, channelBlue, channelGreen, channelRed, NULL);



cvThreshold(channelBlue, Result1, 20, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY);
cvThreshold(channelGreen, Result2, 20, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY);
cvThreshold(channelRed, Result3, 20, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY);





cvShowImage("original", img);

cvShowImage("blue", Result1);
cvShowImage("green", Result2);
cvShowImage("red", Result3);

cvWaitKey(0); 


return 0;
}][1]
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not going to work this way. When you have a single-channel image, opencv assumes it's grayscale.

What you can do is create a blue, red, and green filter images with the same size, filled with 255's in the channel of interest, and all zeroes in the other channels.

Then you just run the following function to get your blue image:

```
cvAnd(original_img,bluefilter_img,blue_result_img)
```

Repeat for the red and green filters.

Comment: "What you can do is create a blue, red, and green filter images with the same size, filled with 255's in the channel of interest, and all zeroes in the other channels." How? :(

Comment: The easiest implementation is the following, there's probably an opencv routine that does it faster:
IplImage* bluefilter = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(myimg),8,3);
for (int y=0;y<bluefilter.height;y++)
for (int x=0;x<bluefilter.width;x++)
{
CV_IMAGE_ELEM(bluefilter,unsigned char, y, 3*x + 0) = 255;
CV_IMAGE_ELEM(bluefilter,unsigned char, y, 3*x + 1) = 0;
CV_IMAGE_ELEM(bluefilter,unsigned char, y, 3*x + 2) = 0;
}

Comment: I don't know what I did wrong.I did the implementation you gave. And the output I got was a full image colored in blue. and the original image turned to BW.                                                           
IplImage* bluefilter = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(img),8,3); 
for (int y=0;y<H;y++) 
for (int x=0;x<W;x++) { 
   CV_IMAGE_ELEM(bluefilter,unsigned char, y, 3*x + 0) = 255; 
   CV_IMAGE_ELEM(bluefilter,unsigned char, y, 3*x + 1) = 0; 
   CV_IMAGE_ELEM(bluefilter,unsigned char, y, 3*x + 2) = 0; 
 }
cvShowImage("original", img);
cvShowImage("blue", bluefilter);
cvWaitKey(0); 
return 0;
}

Answer (score 0):

If you have a 3 channel image, when you use `cvSplit` it gives you 3 gray scale images (and not B&W) because they are single channel images.

img(R,G,B) ==> chRed(R), chGreen(G), chBlue(B) with R, G and B from 0 to 255.

img has 255*255*255 colors and the others only 256.

And you end up with B&W images only because you threshold them afterwards.
You might want to use the last version of OpenCV 2.4.4 and do something more automatic and robust like `threshold(imgIn, imgOut, 100, 255, CV_THRESH_OTSU);`
( see : http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html?highlight=threshold#cv.Threshold )

So if the goal is to have some artistic view, then what perfanoff said is the right way.
But if you are planning to do some kind of work with color detection there is no business having color in your single channel images (as it's not possible).

I don't know if that was clear, let me know.